# php mail() with <style> tag and background-size: cover

Tags: email, styles

I want to style a contact email, but I have a few problems:

1. I sent a test-mail to my gmx mail and it removed the `style="background: url('...') center center no-repeat; position: relative;"`. In the received code I only see `style="position: relative;"`
2. Like the first problem, but with `"background-size: cover;"` and `"width: calc(50% - 3px);"`
3. My `<style>` - tag got commented and looks like this:

Comment: //add:
style="background-image: url('...'); background-repeat: no-repeat;..."
works, but the "background-size: cover;" still doesn't.
And sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: my header contains:

$from .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$from .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

Comment: Edit those things into your question. Less convenient naming those in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting CSS like that does not prevent it working - it just ensures the browser does not treat it as HTML.

gmail strips all classes and ids from HTML, so nothing you put in your style sheet based on those will work anyway. You can style standard elements though, and inline styles still work.

Outlook doesn't support background images at all, so you should probably give up on this path.